# How to remove specific character in string if it is in quotation mark Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string:

```
"Yes, We do. This is a complex issue that deserves more than a one word answer," Zuckerberg said. Pallone called the response "disappointing."
```

What is the best way to remove dot mark (.) if it in between the quotation marks using Python?
the expected result is like:

```
"Yes, We do This is a complex issue that deserves more than a one word answer," Zuckerberg said. Pallone called the response "disappointing"
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture all quotes "..." with regex `(\"[\s\S]*?\")` and handle the replace in a loop. First replace the `.` and store into `newquote`. Then replace the old quote with the new one.

```
import re;

s = '"Yes, We do. This is a complex issue that deserves more than a one word answer," Zuckerberg said. Pallone called the response "disappointing."';

pattern = re.compile(r'(\"[\s\S]*?\")');

for (quote) in re.findall(pattern, s):
    newquote = quote.replace('.', '');
    s = s.replace(quote, newquote);

print s;
```

Comment: Sure. Thanks. Have a great day!